# Replica Sets with MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I want to get MongoVUE set up to work with replica sets. I have followed the instructions found in the link below at step 2(b).

http://www.mongovue.com/2012/03/26/establishing-connections-to-servers-and-replica-sets-using-mongovue/

However all I get is "Connection Refused"

See image: http://snag.gy/PqXmQ.jpg

All instances are running - as windows services if that helps - and as you can see from the image they are all part of a replica set. The notepad at the bottom shows the full text string I have used for the server.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I recently had the same issue

Comment: Could you try IP addresses instead of machine names? If you aren't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Use IP addresses...

I'm just looking back at issues I've had in the past. This looks like it was resolved quite simply by using IP addresses instead of host names.

HTH